# Jasper Report (iReport) Pie Dataset from main dataset

Tags: dataset, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to use a pie chart per group in Jasper iReport, but I don't know how to create a dataset per group.

Assume I have a table as follows:

```
Table users
---------
category - user - status
```

Then I have a the following SQL

```
select * from users order by category
```

My display has a simple group band of category with detail showing each user and their status.  Ideally I would have each category group header show a pie chart with all the distinct statuses and their counts within that group.  I'm at a loss as how to do this in iReport.

If I knew all the categories ahead of time I could just create a dataset for each one using the following:

```
select status, count(user) from user where category = <current category> group by status
```

I'm attempting to do this using a `JRMapCollectionDataSource` that resets each group and pulls the data from the rows in the group using a variable, but I'm not very familiar with the whole reset group and increment paradigm.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this issue without programming following this steps:

1. sort data by ***category*** field and by ***user*** field (add sorting via *iReport* or adding *ORDER BY* clause to the query in case having deal with *jdbc datasource*);
2. add two groups:  the 1st group - for ***category*** field and the 2nd group - for ***user*** field (via *iReport*). **Note**: It is not necessarily to add *GROUP BY* clause to the query;
3. add *Pie Chart* component to the *Group Header* band for the ***category*** field;
4. set ***evaluationTime*** and ***evaluationGroup*** properties for this *pieChart*.

Here is working sample for demonstrating how to build *Pie Chart*. In this sample I've used the *csv* file as datasource.

The chart shows the quantity of *users* for every *category*. I used variable ***usersCount*** for counting *users* in every group, but it is was possible to use built-in variable ***`$V{userGroup_COUNT}`***.

Here is my *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <field name="category" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="user" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <sortField name="category"/>
    <sortField name="user"/>
    <variable name="usersCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="userGroup" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{user}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="categoryGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{category}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="135">
                <pieChart>
                    <chart evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="categoryGroup">
                        <reportElement x="158" y="0" width="200" height="135"/>
                        <chartTitle/>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <pieDataset>
                        <dataset resetType="Group" resetGroup="categoryGroup" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="userGroup"/>
                        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{user}]]></keyExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{usersCount}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[String.valueOf($V{usersCount})]]></labelExpression>
                    </pieDataset>
                    <piePlot>
                        <plot/>
                        <itemLabel/>
                    </piePlot>
                </pieChart>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Category: " + $F{category}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="userGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{user}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is my *csv* file (data file - *datasource*):

```
category,user,status
1,user1,WORK
1,user1,HOLIDAY
1,user2,SICK
2,user1,WORK
2,user2,WORK
2,user2,HOLIDAY
2,user3,HOLIDAY
2,user4,SICK
3,user1,HOLIDAY
3,user3,HOLIDAY
3,user5,HOLIDAY
4,user1,WORK
4,user1,HOLIDAY
4,user2,SICK
4,user2,WORK
4,user2,SICK
4,user3,HOLIDAY
4,user4,HOLIDAY
4,user5,HOLIDAY
```

The result will be (via *iReport* preview):

[image: The result]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the reset type and increment type before seeing your example.  It seems so straightforward now.